# creating multiple store on same domain magento

Tags: store-view

I am trying to run two Magento stores via same admin panel i have a magento installed at domain name/magento now as a first step i have go catalog->Manage Category and add two different root category for two different store and set Is Anchor to yesand Is Active to yes now i go to sytem->Manage Store and make other store name magento2 now i go to folder where my magento is installed and make the a folder name magento2 then copy the .htacess and index.phpfrom root folder to magento2 folder then edit the .htacces and index.php file then I have replace the following code

```
"$mageFilename = ‘app/Mage.php’;" with $mageFilename = ‘../app/Mage.php’; and in .htaccess file add the following line at the bottom SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base"; SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="magento2";
```

now i go to system->configuration and the store view to magento2 then i go to genral->web and in base link url option under secure and unsecure tab add the following code

```
{{unsecure_base_url}}magento2/
```

when i open the url `www.mydomain.com/magento/magento2/` then page is displaying only blank page and also www.mydomain.com/magento url not working properly.
Products and categories page are not working. That pages are giving error page not found. 
What should I do now? Any help or suggestions please give.

how to create different store view on same domain magento?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below steps. It worked for me.

**Setp 1**

i) Create folder MAGE_ROOT/magento2/

ii) Copy your magento root index.php and .htaccess

**Setp 2**

i) Open index.php, find below line and replace **your_store_code** with **store code**

`$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'your_store_code'; 
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';`

ii) Open .htaccess files and give your folder path

`RewriteBase /magento2/`

**Step 3**

i) Go to System->Configuration then select store view and General->Web

ii) Under Unsecure and Secure **Base URL** http://yourdomain/magento2/

iii) If ii(setp 3) don't load styles, js and media files, please set yourdomain_link/skin/, yourdomain_link/media/ and yourdomain_link/js/

Hope it will help you. Best of luck!

Comment: how to set media and js files.. is there any code for that and where to add code for that?

Comment: You can set from System->Configuration->(Select Your Store)->General->Web Skin: `http://yourdomain.com/skin, JS: http://yourdomain.com/js, Media: http://yourdomain.com/media`

Answer (score 0):

Update:

**Version Magento 2.3.4**

***Setp 1***

1. Create folder MAGE_ROOT/gcentric/
2. Copy your magento root index.php and .htaccess

***Setp 2***

1. Open index.php. Copy the following lines from comments:

   `$params = $_SERVER;
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';`

Search for the following code snippet and paste above lines before this:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
```

Replace string values 'website2' and 'website' with new store code 'gcentric'.

2. Now, open the .htaccess file in MAGE_ROOT/gcentric/ and add new folder path

RewriteBase /gcentric/

***Step 3***

1. Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration.
2. Change 'Scope' to 'Default Config'.
3. In URL Options, set 'Add Store Code to Urls' to Yes.
4. Change 'Scope' to 'Gcentric'. Update the Base URLs from 'Default Pages' to newly created store.

***Step 4*** 
Since, we are creating multiple stores on the same domain. Therefore, styles, JS, media and skins should work correctly.

> **Assumption:** There is a sub-store created in the existing domain with Store name 'Gcentric.com' and Store code 'gcentric'.